# Help me in implementation of 'TableView' ans 'TableView Cell'

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Im in aproject with the architecture like this:

1. A table view on a view controller.
2. Table cells are structured using 'uitableview cell'
3. when a cell is selected(DidSelectedRow At IndexPath:), the cell expands.
4. the expanded cell should show two views(a. data in first view  &  b. controls in the second view). ie I have to create two classes for drawing a cell.
5. The tableView is parent, the two view classes are child. The loading of Table cell is done from both child cells.

How to get the architecture. One idea i got is to 'Implement table view inside each tableViewCell' . But its very confusing from parent and this cells.

So need an alternative architecture..

Thanks in advance..

Bharath gangupalli

Answer (score 0):

Inherits the UITableViewCell and do whatever you want with this class.